# How can I reset the default message replies on Messages for WatchOS

Tags: messages, apple-watch, watchos

I am messaging friends in multiple languages. The default replies in the Messages app on my Apple Watch were clever enough to be displayed in the according language of the chat depending on what keyboard was enabled. And I was pretty happy with most of them.

However I edited a few to match my personal taste. For example:

```
yes
```

to

```
yep :)
```

Now I would like to reset all the default replies, to their standard in the according language. How can I do that? I cant find a button or similar in the Watch app on my iPhone.

Comment: Can't experiment much, since I no longer have an Apple Watch. However, before, if you deleted all the default responses, Apple would regenerate new ones. Not sure how this works on the newer models though

Comment: @RushilSrivastava I tried deleting all the default replies on my Apple Watch. Now I just have an empty reply list, so I wouldn't recommend trying that.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro i noticed the same thing after one reply. Definitley not recommended.